# MySQL issue with Google Chrome on Windows 8

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, windows-8

I'm using the following call in PHP to add a log to MySQL.

```
 public function addLog($data) {
            $query_one = $this->db->escape($data["one"]);
            $query_two = $this->db->escape($data["two"]);
            $query_three= $this->db->escape($data["three"]);
            $query_four = $this->db->escape($data["four"]);
            $query_five = $this->db->escape($data["five"]);
            $query_six = $this->db->escape($data["six"]);
            $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s A', time()+19800);
                    $top_query = sprintf("insert into log (one,two,three,four,five,six,ts) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s','%s')", $query_one, $query_two, $query_three,$query_four, $query_five, $query_six, $time );
                    error_log($top_query);
                    $top_sql = $this->db->query($top_query);
            #will return true or false
                    return $top_sql;
        }
```

The log entry is not working when I use Google Chrome on WIndows 8. Is there some special handling required?

Comment: The PHP code has no idea what client browser or platform is making the HTTP request that initiates it. Are you actually using a web server, or trying to execute the PHP file with the browser (something like `file:///path/to/php/file.php` in the address bar)?

Comment: I am making use of nginx. This functionality is working perfectly on all other browsers I've tested, including IE and Firefox. It works on Google Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Google Chrome on Mac but when it comes to Chrome specifically for Windowes 8 there seems to be an issue.

Comment: Are you posting data? Is it from a form, or from an AJAX request? There really is no connection between PHP/nginx and the client browser - it's just text passed up and down via HTTP request/response

Comment: As other members have mentioned, it's not important for the PHP code itself which browser or OS you are using. in your case since the function name has a word _Log_ in it, I assume you are creating some kind of log for user activity on your site. so I think there is something wrong with the values inside the `$data` array...
can you post the complete code here or at least tell us what exactly is stored in this array?

Comment: The error must be somewhere else. Perhaps you have some client-side JavaScript that will eventually call the server-side script that runs `addLog()`, and such code is crashing, not running, running differently. Perhaps you have cookie-based features. Perhaps...

Comment: i agree with above, PHP or MySQL does not care about browser, if you are executing the code for sure I think it might be just escaping, what happens if there is a single quote in one of those values? Use PDO instead, helps me to overcome trouble with escaping, echo your $top_query when quotes are present you will see